# React Portal not generating children in functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component, react-portal

I have simple react portal component. Firstly i wrote this in class component and all works very well. But i decided to rewrite this into functional component. And after this portal is only generating div inside div#portal but no children inside. I have no idea where is mistake.

```
// Functional Component

import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom';

const Lightbox = ({ children }) => {
  const portalRoot = document.getElementById('portal');
  const el = document.createElement('div');

  useEffect(() => {
    portalRoot.appendChild(el);

    return () => portalRoot.removeChild(el);
  }, []);

  return createPortal(children, el);
};

export default Lightbox;

// Class component

// import { Component } from 'react';
// import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

// const portalRoot = document.getElementById('portal');

// export default class Lightbox extends Component {
//   constructor() {
//     super();
//     this.el = document.createElement('div');
//   }

//   componentDidMount = () => {
//     portalRoot.appendChild(this.el);
//   };

//   componentWillUnmount = () => {
//     portalRoot.removeChild(this.el);
//   };
//   render() {
//     const { children } = this.props;
//     return ReactDOM.createPortal(children, this.el);
//   }
// }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating the `const el = document.createElement('div');` on every update (because it's in the main function) and it's wrong. In the Class component, you've created this only once inside the `constructor()` so every time it's in that same `div` but in your functional component it's getting change on every render/update.

You can keep the `el` with `useRef()` like:

`const el = useRef(document.createElement('div'));` and use it as `el.current`